# How to make this regex rule case insensitive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm doing the following:

```
email = 'bob@luv.southwest.com'

domain_rules = [/craigslist.org/, /evite.com/, /ziprealty.com/, /alleyinsider.com/, /fedexkinkos.com/, /luv.southwest.com/, /fastsigns.com/, /experts-exchange.com/, /feedburner.com/]

user, domain = email.split('@')

domain_rules.each { |rule| return true if !domain.match(rule).nil? }
```

Problem is this is case sensitive. Is there a way to make this all case insensative, without having to add /i to the end of every single rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`downcase` the email & domain you want to match first, then `find_all` regexp matches.

You can use `find` to only retrieve the first matching "rule".

```
email = 'bob@luv.southwest.com'

domain_rules = [/craigslist.org/, /evite.com/, /ziprealty.com/, /alleyinsider.com/, /fedexkinkos.com/, /luv.southwest.com/, /fastsigns.com/, /experts-exchange.com/, /feedburner.com/]
user, domain = email.split('@').collect { |s| s.downcase }
p domain_rules.find_all { |rule| domain[rule] }
```

There's also no real need for Regexp:

```
email = 'bob@luv.southwest.com'

matchable_domains = %w{ craigslist.org evite.com ziprealty.com alleyinsider.com fedexkinkos.com luv.southwest.com fastsigns.com experts-exchange.com feedburner.com }
user, domain = email.downcase.split('@')
p matchable_domains.find_all { |rule| matchable_domains.include?(domain) }
```

Or, you can do ONLY Regexp:

```
email = 'bob@luv.southwest.com'
regexp = /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(craigslist\.org|evite\.com|ziprealty\.com|alleyinsider\.com|fedexkinkos\.com|luv\.southwest\.com|fastsigns\.com|experts-exchange\.com|feedburner\.com)/

p regexp === email # => true
p regexp.match(email) # => #<MatchData "bob@luv.southwest.com" 1:"bob" 2:"luv.southwest.com">il
```

Comment: Same thing, that's why I love Ruby. This could also be a one-liner if you wanted.

Comment: Why not use `detect` instead of `find_all`?

Comment: @Ryan, is there a difference?

Comment: `detect` is the same as `find`. http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Enumerable:detect

Comment: @c00lryguy thanks. I guess I'm more curious why to use detect instead of find_all

Comment: Oh, `[1, 2, "three"].find {}` is the same as `[1, 2, "three"].detect {}` and `[1, 2, "three"].find_all {}.first`

Comment: The regex patterns leak at the `.` wildcards, so this answer has problems. All wildcards need to be escaped, `\.`.

Comment: Yes, the above example was more showing how to match the domain wih regexp. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html for better examples.

EDIT: Ohh I see, edit'd.

Comment: @c00lryguy: But you are using `find_all`, not `find`. There is a difference that is important: `find_all` will iterate through an array and find ALL the matches when `find` / `detect` will loop through until it finds a SINGLE match and then stops.

Comment: Right, I kind of assumed the op wanted to display all Regexps that matches the email. I now see the op really wanted `Enumerable#any?`

Answer (score 11):

Use the option "i" (ignore case)

```
domain_rules = [
  /craigslist.org/i,
  /evite.com/i,
  /ziprealty.com/i,
  /alleyinsider.com/i,
  /fedexkinkos.com/i,
  /luv.southwest.com/i,
  /fastsigns.com/i,
  /experts-exchange.com/i,
  /feedburner.com/i
]
```

test it here... http://rubular.com/

Comment: Thanks but that's exactly what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this?

Comment: And why not use one rule for all?
`/\bcraigslist.org\b|\bbevite.com\b|\bziprealty.com\b/i`
http://rubular.com/r/aF5Dhv4CFa

Comment: See my edit. It's really about preference. You'll want to benchmark and find the fastest solution if speed becomes a problem but otherwise it's all exactly the same.

Comment: The regex in this answer will leak characters, allowing false positives, because of the `.` wildcard characters. They have to be escaped in order to work correctly.

Comment: This was already pointed out by @BaroqueBobcat but @the Tin Man is absolutely correct... ``.`` will need to be escaped... ``\.``

Answer (score 2):

No need to use regexes for simple string comparisons.

```
email = 'bob@luv.southwest.com'

domains = %w(CraigsList.org evite.com ZiPreAltY.com alleyinsider.com fedexkinkos.com luv.southwest.com fastsigns.com experts-exchange.com feedburner.com)

user, user_domain = email.split('@')

p domains.any? { |domain| domain.casecmp(user_domain).zero? }
```

`String#casecmp` does a case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: Interesting. A result of `0` means it matches and a result of `1` means there is no match.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter [`String#casecmp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-casecmp) returns `0`, `1`, or `-1` to match how `<=>` works and how sorting works.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for that. I also found that you can use `.casecmp?` which returns `true` when there's a match and `false` when there's no match, which seems to be more readable than `.zero?`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make the email address lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see with your current implementation is that it will match domains like luvesouthwestlcom.com, because `.` matches any character. You could deal with this by escaping all the url you are using by doing something like this:

```
email = 'bob@luv.southwest.com'

domains = %w[craigslist.org evite.com ziprealty.com alleyinsider.com fedexkinkos.com luv.southwest.com fastsigns.com experts-exchange.com feedburner.com]

domain_rules = domains.map{|d| /#{Regexp.escape(d)}/i }
user, domain = email.split('@')

domain_rules.any? { |rule| domain.match(rule) }
```

Also, if you are only looking for exact matches, you don't really need regular expressions and could just check to see if the email's domain includes one of the strings you are looking for.

```
email = 'bob@luv.southwest.com'

domains = %w[craigslist.org evite.com ziprealty.com alleyinsider.com fedexkinkos.com luv.southwest.com fastsigns.com experts-exchange.com feedburner.com]

user, domain = email.split('@')
domain.downcase! # lower cases the string in place

domains.any? { |rule| domain.include?(rule) }
```

The issue with either of these is that they will match anything with an exact string in it, so `'craigslist.org'` will match `'nyc.craiglist.org'` and `'craigslist.org.uk'`. If you want exact matches, you could just use `==` after downcasing your input domain. e.g.

```
domains.any? { |rule| domain == rule }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the rules as simple strings and construct the regex on the fly:

```
email = 'bob@luv.southwest.com'

domains = %w(craigslist.org evite.com ziprealty.com) # etc
user, domain = email.split('@').collect { |s| s.downcase }

p domains.any? { |d| domain.match(/#{d}/i) }
```